# GridToolbarColumnsButton change copy

Tags: material-ui

I have a this custom toolbar and I want to change the display copy, but I don't see a prop on the `<GridToolbarColumnsButton />` that will let me do that. Does anyone know how to change the text and icon on the `<GridToolbarColumnsButton />` component.

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the text, you can override the locals via the localeText prop of the DataGrid component
For the other props of this component, you will have to provide your own toolbar. It is a very basic component so copy pasting it is not a big issue.

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-v5-quick-start-forked-d3s3r?file=/src/App.tsx